# Google map data layer opacity control from external button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to control Google maps Data layers Opacity through setStyle. There is a property fillOpacity which takes value between 0.0 and 1.0.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(OpacityPbutton, 'click', function() {
    map.data.setStyle({fillOpacity: '0.4'});
  });
```

I can change the opacity to 0.4 but i need to have it Incremental. like every time i click the button it will increase the opacity by 0.1. your suggestion is much appreciated.

Please check the  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rabbishakir/fbe6j93f/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function OpControl(controlDiv, map) {

  controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

  // Set CSS for the control wrapper
  var controlWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  controlWrapper.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  controlWrapper.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  controlWrapper.style.borderColor = 'gray';
  controlWrapper.style.borderWidth = '1px';
  controlWrapper.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlWrapper.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlWrapper.style.width = '32px';
  controlWrapper.style.height = '64px';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlWrapper);

  // Set CSS for the Opacity Plus
  var OpacityPbutton = document.createElement('div');
  OpacityPbutton.style.width = '32px';
  OpacityPbutton.style.height = '32px';
  OpacityPbutton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://placehold.it/32/00ff00")';
  controlWrapper.appendChild(OpacityPbutton);

  // Set CSS for the Opacity Minus
  var OpacityMbutton = document.createElement('div');
  OpacityMbutton.style.width = '32px';
  OpacityMbutton.style.height = '32px';
  OpacityMbutton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://placehold.it/32/0000ff")';
  controlWrapper.appendChild(OpacityMbutton);

  // Setup the click event listener - Opacity plus
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(OpacityPbutton, 'click', function() {
    // map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
    map.data.setStyle({
      fillOpacity: '0.4'
    });

  });

  // Setup the click event listener - Opacity Minus
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(OpacityMbutton, 'click', function() {
    // map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
    map.data.setStyle({
      fillOpacity: '0.8'
    });
  });

}

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: {
      lat: -33.865143,
      lng: 151.209900
    }
  });

  var opacityControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var opControl = new OpControl(opacityControlDiv, map);

  opacityControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(opacityControlDiv);

  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json');

  // Set mouseover event for each feature.
  map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    document.getElementById('info-box').textContent =
      event.feature.getProperty('ascii');
  });

}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, keep the value of the current opacity in a variable, increment it (or decrement it when the button is clicked.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(OpacityPbutton, 'click', function() {
   opacity += opacityInc;
   if (opacity >= 0.9) opacityInc = -opacityInc;
   if (opacity <= 0.009999) opacityInc = -opacityInc;
   document.getElementById('opacity').innerHTML = opacity;
    map.data.setStyle({fillOpacity: opacity});
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/3gqLvo16/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var opacity = 0.1;
var opacityInc = 0.1;

function OpControl(controlDiv, map) {

  controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

  // Set CSS for the control wrapper
  var controlWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  controlWrapper.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  controlWrapper.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  controlWrapper.style.borderColor = 'gray';
  controlWrapper.style.borderWidth = '1px';
  controlWrapper.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlWrapper.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlWrapper.style.width = '32px';
  controlWrapper.style.height = '32px';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlWrapper);

  // Set CSS for the Opacity Plus
  var OpacityPbutton = document.createElement('div');
  OpacityPbutton.style.width = '32px';
  OpacityPbutton.style.height = '32px';
  OpacityPbutton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://placehold.it/32/00ff00")';
  controlWrapper.appendChild(OpacityPbutton);

  // Setup the click event listener - Opacity plus
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(OpacityPbutton, 'click', function() {
    // map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
    opacity += opacityInc;
    if (opacity >= 0.9) opacityInc = -opacityInc;
    if (opacity <= 0.009999) opacityInc = -opacityInc;
    document.getElementById('opacity').innerHTML = opacity;
    map.data.setStyle({
      fillOpacity: opacity
    });

  });
}

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: {
      lat: -33.865143,
      lng: 151.209900
    }
  });

  var opacityControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var opControl = new OpControl(opacityControlDiv, map);

  opacityControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(opacityControlDiv);

  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json');

  // Set mouseover event for each feature.
  map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    document.getElementById('info-box').textContent =
      event.feature.getProperty('ascii');
  });

}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="opacity"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```